# what am i doing wrong with confusion matrix

Tags: statsmodels, confusion-matrix, scipy.stats

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable exp method

I keep getting this error. all libraries are imported correctly. I have changed the dummies variables to a float. what am I missing? i have posted the libraries i used as well as code

[screenshot_code_part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8l6W.png)
[screensshot_code_part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pR0T.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Library to split data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# libaries to help with data visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Removes the limit for the number of displayed columns
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)

# To build Logistic Regression model for prediction
import statsmodels.stats.api as sms
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tools.tools import add_constant
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# To get diferent metric scores
from sklearn.metrics import (
    f1_score,
    accuracy_score,
    recall_score,
    precision_score,
    confusion_matrix,
    roc_auc_score,
    precision_recall_curve,
    roc_curve,
    make_scorer
)

# Libraries to build decision tree classifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import tree

# To tune different models
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

```
def model_performance_classification_statsmodels(
    model, predictors, target, threshold=0.5
):
    """
    Function to compute different metrics to check classification model performance

    model: classifier
    predictors: independent variables
    target: dependent variable
    threshold: threshold for classifying the observation as class 1
    """

    # checking which probabilities are greater than threshold
    pred_temp = model.predict(predictors) > threshold
    # rounding off the above values to get classes
    pred = np.round(pred_temp)

    acc = accuracy_score(target, pred)  # to compute Accuracy
    recall = recall_score(target, pred)  # to compute Recall
    precision = precision_score(target, pred)  # to compute Precision
    f1 = f1_score(target, pred)  # to compute F1-score

    # creating a dataframe of metrics
    df_perf = pd.DataFrame(
        {"Accuracy": acc, "Recall": recall, "Precision": precision, "F1": f1,},
        index=[0],
    )

    return df_perf
```

```
def confusion_matrix_statsmodels(model, predictors, target, threshold=0.5):
    """
    To plot the confusion_matrix with percentages

    model: classifier
    predictors: independent variables
    target: dependent variable
    threshold: threshold for classifying the observation as class 1
    """
    y_pred = model.predict(predictors) > threshold
    cm = confusion_matrix(target, y_pred)
    labels = np.asarray(
        [
            ["{0:0.0f}".format(item) + "\n{0:.2%}".format(item / cm.flatten().sum())]
            for item in cm.flatten()
        ]
    ).reshape(2, 2)

    plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
    sns.heatmap(cm, annot=labels, fmt="")
    plt.ylabel("True label")
    plt.xlabel("Predicted label")
```